# If Checkbox checked perfom a function

Tags: php, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have this website i'm doing for and I need to when the checkbox is selected add the value to the SUB TOTAL.

The value comes in $ and its like this `<?php echo $rare['value']; ?>`

Now the checkbox is this `<input type="checkbox" name="buy" value="buy">Buy<br>`

So I want to, when the multiple checkboxes are selected, they add the price (or the value) of each time into a SUB TOTAL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check that a POST value is submitted for the field:

```
if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
  // do something with your value
}
```

Comment: Its for a shop basically and there will be a list of products, and so the checkboxes will be selected for the products you want to buy, and when you select them checkboxes the price will add up in the SUB TOTAL box

Answer (score 0):

And you can also give it a name as an array and make it easier if you have multiple checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="values[]"'>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="values[]"'>
...
```

To check the values you simple do:

```
if(isset($_POST['values'])) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Its for a shop basically and there will be a list of products, and so the checkboxes will be selected for the products you want to buy, and when you select them checkboxes the price will add up in the SUB TOTAL box

Comment: do you want to do this live (ajax+jquery), or just after the user clicks submit?

Comment: yes it is, but you just have to send the attribute of the checkbox to a javascript fucntion, which will call an ajax request and edit the price.. which makes it a different matter entirely.

Comment: Would it be easier, If I did a list of Products with name and price and check box then at the end a submit box and on the confirmation page the subtotal?

Comment: How whould I do it though to add up only the ones selected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" value="100" name="values[]" class="buyThis">
            <input type="checkbox" value="200" name="values[]" class="buyThis">
            <input type="checkbox" value="300" name="values[]" class="buyThis">
            <div><span>SUB TOTAL : $</span><span id="subTotal">0</span></div>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.buyThis').removeAttr('checked');
        $('.buyThis').on('click', function(){
            var subTotalVal = Number($('#subTotal').text());
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                subTotal = eval(subTotalVal) + eval($(this).val());
            } else {
                subTotal = eval(subTotalVal) - eval($(this).val());
            }
            $('#subTotal').text(subTotal);
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```